# How to reduce the query time on large data table with self inner join in DB2?

Tags: optimization, db2

I have a table called 'ASSETINFO' in DB2 .This table has 3 MILLION records.
I want to fetch the records based on 'Asset Price Range' from the table, so I have applied Inner Join on the same table on Id column.
Currently, the table has 202964 rows but it is taking more than 20 mins to run. 
I tried the below query even that is taking more than 15 mins.-

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM AI
INNER JOIN AI AI2
ON AI2.ASSET_ID = AI.ASSET_ID
WHERE AI2.ASSET_ID = 123;
```

My Query is:

```
select AI.ASSET_ID,
AI.ASSET_NAME,
AI.ASSET_START_PRIZE,
AI.ASSET_END_PRICE,
AI3.ASSET_START_PRIZE,
AI3.ASSET_END_PRICE,
AI.ASSET_AREA_CODE
FROM ASSETINFO AI
INNER JOIN 
    ( SELECT
    AI2.ASSET_ID,
    AI2.ASSET_NAME,
    AI2.ASSET_START_PRIZE,
    AI2.ASSET_END_PRICE,
    AI2.ASSET_AREA_CODE
    FROM ASSETINFO AI2
    WHERE AI2.ASSET_ID=123
    GROUP BY 
    AI2.ASSET_ID,
    AI2.ASSET_NAME,
    AI2.ASSET_START_PRIZE,
    AI2.ASSET_END_PRICE,
    AT2.ASSET_AREA_CODE
    ) AI2
ON AI3.ASSET_ID = AI.ASSET_ID,
AND AI3.ASSET_AREA_CODE = AI.ASSET_AREA_CODE
AND AI.ASSET_START_PRIZE > AI3.ASSET_START_PRIZE
AND AI.ASSET_END_PRICE < AI3.ASSET_END_PRICE
WHERE AI.ASSET_ID=123
    GROUP BY 
    AI3.ASSET_ID,
    AI3.ASSET_NAME,
    AI3.ASSET_START_PRIZE,
    AI3.ASSET_END_PRICE,
    AI3.ASSET_AREA_CODE
    ORDER BY 
    AI3.ASSET_ID, AI3.ASSET_NAME;
```

Please suggest, if in the above case how can I reduce the time? Do I need to use the INDEX, if yes, which index would be useful in my case?

Comment: You have also used a subquery but Idont see why this couldnt just be a single query on its own. You ask us about indexes but you havent told is what indexes already exist.

Comment: Your first query would benefit from idexes on asset_id if there isnt one already. 3 million records isnt that big, if counting records takes that long i think you have more than one problem.

Comment: Current indexes are on 'ASSET_ID,ASSET_FAMILY_ID,ASSET_AREA_ID) its a regular index.

Comment: yes, that's right, but I don't get why my query is taking that long time? I would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, you can use [db2advis](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002452.html) to figure out which indexes would help your query

Answer (score 0):

If this is taking 15 minutes then something is wrong
Is ASSET_ID indexed?
Have you fragmented indexes lately?

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM AI
INNER JOIN AI AI2
ON AI2.ASSET_ID = AI.ASSET_ID
WHERE AI2.ASSET_ID = 123;
```

Comment: Yes, ASSET_ID in there in index, no I didn't fragmented the index.

Comment: The above query is taking more than five minutes. Do you think I need to create Index on different keys?

Comment: One step at a time.  Did you defragment?  Don't post update in comments.  Update the question with the indexes.

Comment: no, I didn't defragment.